# Creating hidden/private directories FileManager Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

My app needs to have a hidden/private(if possible) folder for storing audio files that the app generates itself. This audio files are used to build  Database where only the App can populate and delete if needed.

The only activity that the user is able to do is exporting some of this file in a folder called "exported" into either the share folder or the iCloud.

The question is, how do I create this hidden/private folder where a User has no permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lazy var documentsUrl:URL = { return fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! }()
lazy var appInternalMusic:URL = { documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(".InternalFolder") }()  
try! fileManager.createDirectory(at: appInternalMusic, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
```

Comment: so, this is the same code from the question? how can it help?

Comment: What the purpose of writing this question on accepted answer?

Comment: I had an approach and turns out it was correct. I have edited the question.

Comment: So have you done downloading data with pause and resume functionality and encrypt data and save to file manager?

Comment: that was no part of the final question